# Is it bad practice to store a Pandas DataFrame as a PickledObjectField in a Django Model?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am storing a Pandas DataFrame in a Django model as a PickledObjectField. I need to access and modify this DataFrame based on certain logic. Pandas makes this job a lot easier, where I have an engine class that uses Pandas selects and filters.

Should I have a separate model where I store each row in the DataFrame, then read this using django-pandas, perform the manipulation and update the model? The key here is that the DataFrame will be modified by adding/removing some rows, so if it is to be stored in a model, it would be easier to drop all records and re-populate the model.

The DataFrame is less than 100 rows, so I'm not worried about scalability.

Answer (score 0):

You might have incompatibility issues after upgrading pandas if you save the data frames as picked objects.

If you don't need to manipulate individual row of the data frame then **I wouldn't add a new Django model** to save the records because every time I need to use them I have to

- read them all into a DataFrame,
- do some work,
- delete all rows related to this DataFrame,
- and finally bulk save them again.

My suggestion is to **dump the DataFrame as a CSV file** and save its location on the same model where you have the PickledObjectField now.

```
df.to_csv('path/to/dataframe.csv')
```

Using the CSV file, you can

```
df = pandas.read_csv('path/to/dataframe.csv')
```

Comment: The problem is that I have a model "users", and for every user I would need to have a different DataFrame based on changing attributes for the users. The main changes are deleting records from the dataframe, so I ended up using a model "Disabled", where there is a link between every user and its disabled records from the original dataframe